# Ayuda consulta XML en sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, xml

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy recibiendo el siguiente XML y necesito obtener los valores

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <TipoTerceroResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <TipoTerceroResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entities.Dto" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:TipoTerceroDto>
                <a:Activo>true</a:Activo>
                <a:Codigo>1</a:Codigo>
                <a:CodigoTercero>10</a:CodigoTercero>
                <a:FechaActualizacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaActualizacion>
                <a:FechaCreacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaCreacion>
                <a:Nombre>Proveedor</a:Nombre>
                <a:NombreAbreviado>PRV</a:NombreAbreviado>
                <a:UsuarioActualizacion>dbo</a:UsuarioActualizacion>
                <a:UsuarioCreacion>dbo</a:UsuarioCreacion>
            </a:TipoTerceroDto>
            <a:TipoTerceroDto>
                <a:Activo>true</a:Activo>
                <a:Codigo>3</a:Codigo>
                <a:CodigoTercero>7</a:CodigoTercero>
                <a:FechaActualizacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaActualizacion>
                <a:FechaCreacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaCreacion>
                <a:Nombre>Asegurado</a:Nombre>
                <a:NombreAbreviado>ASEG</a:NombreAbreviado>
                <a:UsuarioActualizacion>dbo</a:UsuarioActualizacion>
                <a:UsuarioCreacion>dbo</a:UsuarioCreacion>
            </a:TipoTerceroDto>
            <a:TipoTerceroDto>
                <a:Activo>true</a:Activo>
                <a:Codigo>4</a:Codigo>
                <a:CodigoTercero>9</a:CodigoTercero>
                <a:FechaActualizacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaActualizacion>
                <a:FechaCreacion>2009-06-11T11:19:47.25</a:FechaCreacion>
                <a:Nombre>Beneficiario</a:Nombre>
                <a:NombreAbreviado>BEN</a:NombreAbreviado>
                <a:UsuarioActualizacion>dbo</a:UsuarioActualizacion>
                <a:UsuarioCreacion>dbo</a:UsuarioCreacion>
            </a:TipoTerceroDto>
        </TipoTerceroResult>
    </TipoTerceroResponse>
</s:Body>
```

y lo estoy consultado de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @DatosXML, '<root xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entities.Dto"  />'

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, '/s:Envelope/s:Body/TipoTerceroResponse/TipoTerceroResult/a:TipoTerceroDto',2) 
WITH (  Activo BIT
       ,codigo INT
       ,CodigoTercero INT
       ,FechaActualizacion DATETIME
       ,FechaCreacion DATETIME
      ,Nombre VARCHAR(150)
      ,NombreAbreviado VARCHAR(150)
      ,UsuarioActualizacion VARCHAR(150)
      ,UsuarioCreacion VARCHAR(150)
        )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

pero no funciona, por favor me podrian ayudar

Comment: ¿Qué error te envía o por qué no te funciona?

Comment: no trae nada en la consulta